# MySQL on VM or Kubernetes for production?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

We are moving from AWS to our own private cloud service. It provides VMs and Kubernetes as managed service. I am working on setting up MySQL. Should I go with VM or kubernetes for this? If it's up to me, what are the pros and cons I should be aware of with both the options?

I am reading different articles but no straight up conclusion.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) . Also check out the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and 
[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run MySQL from either a VM or Kubernetes.  But keep in mind that a relational database is a 100% stateful microservice.  Therefore, at the course grain level, we cannot simply bring up more pods to scale horizontally.  It is possible to horizontally scale a MySQL database, but would be fine grain, e.g. using a sharding key.  So some of the benefits which a stateless microservice enjoys on K8s would not apply to MySQL.